# threejs radial gradient effect on a sphere

Tags: three.js

I want to do a sort of "inner glow", where a partially transparent color is more intense towards the outside of a sphere, as the user looks at it.

In plain ol' CSS it would be pretty simple:

```css
.gradient{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 50px 1px inset rgba(0,225,255,0.8);
  background: rgba(0,225,255,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial has this effect](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html), and I have a separate [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710027/implement-custom-webgl-shaders-in-vuejs) about an issue I ran into implementing if anyone else has trouble.

Some custom GL shaders: this is GL code that lives in a string to get compiled later:

```
const vertexShader = `
    uniform vec3 viewVector;
    uniform float c;
    uniform float p;
    varying float intensity;
    void main()
    {
        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
        intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }`;

const fragmentShader = `
    uniform vec3 glowColor;
    varying float intensity;
    void main() 
    {
        vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
        gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
    }`;
```

This is the material to create the effect. Play with `c` and `p` values for intensity/depth of the "gradient".

```
const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.5 },
        "p":   { type: "f", value: 2 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x00e1ff) },
        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: camera.position }
    },
    vertexShader:   vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```

You'll want to apply it to your geometry, and scalar your geometry up to the size of "shell" you desire.

```
const moonGlow = new THREE.Mesh( Orb, customMaterial);
moonGlow.position = moon.position;
moonGlow.scale.multiplyScalar(1.2);
scene.add( moonGlow );
```

Finally, facing is important. In you're changing up positions, like in an animation loop with motion controls, add this:

```
customMaterial.uniforms.viewVector.value = camera.position;
```