# Implement custom WebGL shaders in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, three.js, webgl, vertex-shader

I found a three.js [example of an effect](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html) I'm attempting, but the implementation doesn't appear to be explained, and may be an older version of three/js. I'm also just getting into three.js/WebGL, so I may just be plain wrong about things.

```
vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
```

The example uses "shaders", which are in script tags with the `type="x-shader/x-vertex"` attribute. I'm able to put the script tags in my head and everything works as advertised.

However, I'm using VueJS, and so I really would rather not put these in my index.html file. I tried to just inject the string directly to the material:

```
const vertexShader = `
    uniform vec3 viewVector;
    uniform float c;
    uniform float p;
    varying float intensity;
    void main()
    {
        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
        intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
    
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
`;
```

And:

```
vertexShader: vertexShader,
```

But I get a

> THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false
>
> Program Info Log: Fragment shader is not compiled.

So I tried to actually put it in a created script tag thinking the browser must be doing some magic:

```
const createShader = (text) => {
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.setAttribute("type", "x-shader/x-vertex");
    const tnode = document.createTextNode(text);
    tag.appendChild(tnode);
    
    document.head.appendChild(tag);
    return tag.textContent;
}
```

And:

```
vertexShader: createShader(vertexShader),
```

But that has the same issue.

Is there a clean way to make this happen, or is direct code on page load the only option?

Comment: A frag and vert shader only needs to be a string, nothing more. So there's no need to create all those DOM nodes, that's just a trick to extract a multi-line string in a single HTML page demo. `const fragShader = "some really long string"` should do the trick in Vue. The issue is probably on compilation, there might be an error in your shader. Have you tried debugging in the Firefox console? They have a much more robust shader error reporting, it even gives you the line where the error took place.

Comment: Are `projectionMatrix`, `modelViewMatrix` globals defined by WebGL or somehow automagically injected by Three.js because I don't see them declared anywhere. Also, is there a typo in `vNormel` near `dot(vNormal, vNormel)`?

Comment: @teddybeard Not those, but it was a typo, `tvec3` should just be `vec3` this is probably just a fatfinger error. @Marquizzo confirming that just the string "should do the trick"  definitely helped also.